# Importing .skp files in blender

Tags: python, ruby, blender, sketchup

I am looking for a way to import `.skp` files into `blender`. The only idea that I have right now is that if i can somehow programmatically import the sketchup files into sketchup and than export them as .dae files than i can run those model in blender.

Is this possible using the `Python API for blender` and `Ruby API for sketchup` ?  Or is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but this question points to a programmatic way of converting/exporting SketchUp files: [Is there a command line in Google Sketchup to export in 3ds or fbx format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246082/is-there-a-command-line-in-google-sketchup-to-export-in-3ds-or-fbx-format)

I'm sure it is possible to adapt this aproach to export .dae (Collada).

Answer (score 0):

Exists an add-on - **Importer for Sketchup** - that enable an option submenu for import .skp files.

It's opensource, hosted on Github with the repository name ***[pyslapi](https://github.com/martijnberger/pyslapi)*** and your developer - **martijnberger**, aka **Juicyfruit** - has posted more informations in the forum **blenderartists.org** in the following link - [click me](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?360406-Sketchup-(SKP)-importer).

It's have some UV issues but looks promissor.